# Website is not opening in selenium webdriver of google chrome using python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to open the website in selenium python but it is showing blank page. but when i open that website in normal google chrome it is working .

here is the code i am writing to open the website.

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://shop.coles.com.au/a/wentworth-point/home")
```

Error I am Getting in chrome console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 () and Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME –

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: yes in console it is showing that `GET https://shop.coles.com.au/a/wentworth-point/specials/browse 429`

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the chromedriver path. Something like this:

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/navget

Comment: driver is working fine but website in not loading.... it is showing blank webpage

Comment: did the chrome browser open and you see that the url go to https://shop.coles.com.au/a/wentworth-point/home?

Comment: yes  every time i run the script browser is running and url is also going to shop.coles.com.au/a/wentworth-point/home

Comment: i mean the python script open the browser and go to the page?

Comment: yes . the only thing which is not happening is , Website is not displaying, insted of website blank page is showing

Comment: try to add time.sleep(120) after the driver.get and see if it loads. Also check if there are javascript errors.

Comment: in chrome console there are 2 errors :-  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()` and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: @kartikchauhan Had you added all these info within the main question, you would have got canonical answers by now for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that version of chrome driver is same of chrome browser installed on your machine
and make sure that path of chrome driver is set in your PATH variable.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

The error code 429 that you are getting means too many requests are sent in a given amount time. Just try to clean your build history and run it again. Regarding the version of Chrome, if that was to be the issue the browser must have not opened in the first place and you would have got other exception like `SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83`

Just to be sure you mat check for the version of chrome you are using and the driver downloaded in the system, if it is not appropriate download the latest chrome driver from web and provide in the executable path to chrome or else add it in environment variables of your system.